# Snowflake SQL to generate gap records for intervals based on start and end dates by joining child relationship

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables parent and child, I'm trying join the two tables on `parentid` and build a contiguous timeseries based on start and end dates from both tables

`Parent` table:

| parentid | start date | end date | parentnm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-09-02 | Name1 |
| 1 | 2023-09-03 | 9999-12-31 | Name2 |

`Child` table

| parentid | start date | end date | child |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-15 | A |
| 1 | 2023-07-05 | 2023-09-10 | C |
| 1 | 2023-10-05 | 2023-10-10 | D |

Since I'm still learning snowflake SQL and recursive CTEs, I'm hoping for some help which could get the desired output

The desired output should populate the respective child id for those between the date ranges of parent id and parent records with null child if its outbound the child end date

Output

| parentid | start_date | end_date | child | parentnm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-15 | A | Name1 |
| 1 | 2023-02-16 | 2023-07-04 |  | Name1 |
| 1 | 2023-07-05 | 2023-09-02 | C | Name1 |
| 1 | 2023-09-03 | 2023-09-10 | C | Name2 |
| 1 | 2023-09-11 | 2023-10-04 |  | Name2 |
| 1 | 2023-10-05 | 2023-10-10 | D | Name2 |
| 1 | 2023-10-11 | 9999-12-31 |  | Name2 |

This is what I tried to use:

```
WITH RECURSIVE DateRanges AS 
(
    -- Anchor member: Starting with the date ranges from table_one
    SELECT 
        parentid, start_date, end_date, NULL AS child, parentnm
    FROM 
        table_one
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive member: Add date ranges from table_two
    SELECT 
        t1.parentid,
        CASE 
            WHEN t2.start_date <= t1.end_date THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, t1.end_date)
            ELSE t2.start_date
        END AS start_date,
        CASE 
            WHEN t2.end_date <= t1.end_date THEN t2.end_date
            ELSE t1.end_date
        END AS end_date,
        t2.child, parentnm
    FROM 
        DateRanges t1
    JOIN 
        table_two t2 ON t1.parentid = t2.parentid
                     AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, t1.end_date) <= t2.start_date
)
-- Selecting the final result
SELECT 
    idnumber, start_date, end_date, child, parentnm
FROM 
    DateRanges
ORDER BY 
    idnumber, start_date;
```

but this is exploding the table due to recursive method.

Any help? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need recursion to solve this (or if there is even a possible solution using recursion) but the following should give you what you want. It can probably be simplified, unused columns removed, CTEs combined, etc. but as it stands it hopefully makes the approach clear:

```
-- assign child records to the appropriate parent record
with child_data as (
    select
    p.parentid
    ,p.start_date p_start_date, p.end_date p_end_date
    ,c.start_date c_start_date, c.end_date c_end_date
    , c.child
    , case when c.start_date > p.start_date then c.start_date else p.start_date end start_date
    , case when c.end_date < p.end_date then c.end_date else p.end_date end as end_date
    , p.parentnm
    from table_one p
    left outer join table_two c on p.parentid = c.parentid and
        (c.start_date between p.start_date and p.end_date or
         c.end_date between p.start_date and p.end_date)
),
-- Identify gaps between child records that need to be filled
parent_data1 as (
    select *
    ,lead(start_date) over (partition by parentid order by start_date asc) lead_start_date
    from child_data
),
-- Calculate records that will fill the gaps
parent_data2 as (
    select * 
    ,case 
        when lead_start_date is null then dateadd('day',1, end_date)
        when lead_start_date <> dateadd('day',1, end_date) then dateadd('day',1, end_date) 
        else null end as calc_start_date
    ,case 
        when lead_start_date is null then p_end_date
        when lead_start_date <> dateadd('day',1, end_date) then dateadd('day',-1, lead_start_date) 
        else null end as calc_end_date
    from parent_data1
    where calc_start_date is not null
)
-- Combine child records and gap-filling records
select 
parentid, start_date, end_date, child, parentnm
from child_data
union
select parentid, calc_start_date, calc_end_date, null, parentnm
from parent_data2
order by parentid, start_date
;
```